How to solve ambiguous ruling?
Disclaimer: this is an slice of an bigger parser - reduced down to just explain my problem
i got the situation that i can haven 3 types of Identifier-starting rhs value - the . and : is only an example for rules starting with an identifier and then differ someway - also the struct copies are just for this example
so it can be just id, id.id or id:id the problem is that the id rule comes first and dictates what is needed at that point - do i need to combine my rules into one to get the different outputs? until now i though that the 3 rules starting with id will be handle as some sort of rule-composit - but it don't seem so
Live on Coliru
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <variant>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast
{
    struct Identifier : std::string
    {
    };
    struct QualifiedId1
    {
        Identifier a, b;
    };
    struct QualifiedId2
    {
        Identifier a, b;
    };

    using Variants = std::variant<Identifier, QualifiedId1, QualifiedId2>;

} // namespace Ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( Ast::QualifiedId1, a, b )
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( Ast::QualifiedId2, a, b )

using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;

template <typename Attr, typename Skipper>
void run_tests( qi::rule<It, Attr(), Skipper> const& rule_, std::vector<std::string> const& tests )
{
    std::cout << "======[ " << boost::core::demangle( typeid( Attr ).name() ) << " ]======" << std::endl;
    for( std::string_view test : tests )
    {
        It f = test.begin(), l = test.end();
        try
        {
            std::cout << "Parsing: " << quoted( test );
            Attr v;
            bool ok;

            if constexpr( std::is_same_v<Skipper, qi::unused_type> )
                ok = qi::parse( f, l, qi::eps > rule_ > qi::eoi, v );
            else
                ok = qi::phrase_parse( f, l, qi::eps > rule_ > qi::eoi, Skipper{}, v );

            std::cout << ( ok ? "OK" : "FAIL" ) << " Remaining: " << quoted( std::string( f, l ) ) << "\n";
        }
        catch( qi::expectation_failure<It> const& ef )
        {
            auto p = ef.first - test.begin();
            auto bol = test.find_last_of( "\r\n", p ) + 1;
            auto line = std::count( f, f + bol, '\n' ) + 1;
            auto eol = test.find_first_of( "\r\n", p );

            std::cout << " -> EXPECTED " << ef.what_ << " in line:" << line << " col:" << ( p - bol ) << "\n"
                      << "    " << test.substr( bol, eol - bol ) << "\n"
                      << "    " << std::setw( p - bol ) << "" << "^--- here\n";
        }
        std::cout << "--------------------\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Identifier()> id = qi::char_( "a-zA-Z_" ) >> *qi::char_( "a-zA-Z0-9_" );
    qi::rule<It, Ast::QualifiedId1(), qi::space_type> qualId1 = id > "." > id;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::QualifiedId2(), qi::space_type> qualId2 = id > ":" > id;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Variants(), qi::space_type> variants = ( id ) | ( qualId1 ) | ( qualId1 );

    run_tests( variants, { "abc", "abc.def", "abc:def" } );
}

Output - the id rule gets handled first and then the expectations fail
======[ class std::variant<struct Ast::Identifier,struct Ast::QualifiedId1,struct Ast::QualifiedId2> ]======
Parsing: "abc"OK Remaining: ""
--------------------
Parsing: "abc.def" -> EXPECTED <eoi> in line:1 col:3
    abc.def
       ^--- here
--------------------
Parsing: "abc:def" -> EXPECTED <eoi> in line:1 col:3
    abc:def
       ^--- here
--------------------

i tried to combine the 3 rules in something like
qi::rule<It, Ast::Variants(), qi::space_type> variants2 = id > *( ( "." > id ) | ( ":" > id ) );

that parses but only give the id type for all 3 in the variant
the following id is only a example normally there are different rules behind (like only numbers or a fixed string etc.) - so not only . and : as difference

In Boost Spirit, the expectation operator (a > b) requires that the following parser match the input, or an exception is emitted.  When id alternative is tried and fails, the exception is thrown, and qualId1 alternative never gets a chance to be attempted.  (I defer to sehe for a better assessment.  This is just my quick 2¢.)  PS:  I like your coding style.

@Eljay - thanks for your 2 cents - my problems started the moment i started switching from >> to > for better error reporting
I like your coding style. i try to adapt sehes style to ease communication here - his style is very readable and easy

Also, ( id ) | ( qualId1 ) | ( qualId1 ) looks like it has one-too-many qualId1.

you're right - doesn't change anything - as expected :)

The alternative operator (a | b) tries each alternative operand one by one on a first-match-wins basis starting from the leftmost operand.  Since id will "win" in all 3 cases, the other rules are never attempted.

@Eljay I like the style too :)

PEG grammars are left-to-right greedy. (a | ab) will never parse ab.
Also, expectation points fail the surrounding rule, not just the containing expression. If backtracking is required, expectation points should not be used.
Fixing these things:
Live On Coliru
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <variant>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast {
    struct Identifier : std::string {
        using std::string::string;
        using std::string::operator=;
    };
    struct QualifiedId1 { Identifier a, b; };
    struct QualifiedId2 { Identifier a, b; };

    using Variants = std::variant<Identifier, QualifiedId1, QualifiedId2>;
} // namespace Ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::QualifiedId1, a, b)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(Ast::QualifiedId2, a, b)

using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;

template <typename Attr, typename Skipper>
void run_tests(qi::rule<It, Attr(), Skipper> const& rule_, std::vector<std::string> const& tests) {
    using boost::core::demangle;
    std::cout << "======[ " << demangle(typeid(Attr).name()) << " ]======" << std::endl;
    for (std::string_view test : tests) {
        It f = test.begin(), l = test.end();
        try {
            std::cout << "Parsing: " << quoted(test) << " -> ";
            Attr v;
            bool ok;

            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Skipper, qi::unused_type>)
                ok = parse(f, l, qi::eps > rule_ > qi::eoi, v);
            else
                ok = phrase_parse(f, l, qi::eps > rule_ > qi::eoi, Skipper{}, v);

            std::cout << (ok ? "OK" : "FAIL")                        //
                      << " Remaining: " << quoted(std::string(f, l)) //
                      << " Variant #" << v.index() << "\n";
        } catch (qi::expectation_failure<It> const& ef) {
            auto p = ef.first - test.begin();
            auto bol = test.find_last_of( "\r\n", p ) + 1;
            auto line = std::count( f, f + bol, '\n' ) + 1;
            auto eol = test.find_first_of( "\r\n", p );

            std::cout << "EXPECTED " << ef.what_ << " in line:" << line << " col:" << ( p - bol ) << "\n"
                      << "    " << test.substr( bol, eol - bol ) << "\n"
                      << "    " << std::setw( p - bol ) << "" << "^--- here\n";
        }
    }
}

template <typename Attr> using Rule = qi::rule<It, Attr(), qi::space_type>;

int main() {
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Identifier()> id = qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_");
    Rule<Ast::QualifiedId1>         qualId1  = id >> ("." > id);
    Rule<Ast::QualifiedId2>         qualId2  = id >> (":" > id);
    Rule<Ast::Variants>             variants = qualId1 | qualId2 | id;

    run_tests( variants, { "abc", "abc.def", "abc:def" } );
}

Prints
======[ std::variant<Ast::Identifier, Ast::QualifiedId1, Ast::QualifiedId2> ]======
Parsing: "abc" -> OK Remaining: "" Variant #0
Parsing: "abc.def" -> OK Remaining: "" Variant #1
Parsing: "abc:def" -> OK Remaining: "" Variant #2

Other Approaches
Sometimes you can mix lookahead assertions to allow for more stringent expectations:
keywordXYZ >> 
   (!qualId2 >> id) // will not parse qualid2

In general, if b matches a subset of a the tricky case (a | bc) can be made to work with (a - b | bc), or equivalently (!b >> a | bc)
BONUS Recursive ASTs
In practice this kind of grammar often appears with expression parsing (where this expression denotes namespace/object member access). Then usually the syntax is recursive:
using IdExpr = boost::variant<         //
    Id,                                //        boost::recursive_wrapper<QualId1>, //
    boost::recursive_wrapper<QualId2>>;

In that case you can often avoid backtracking and incrementally build the attribute using semantic actions:
Live On Coliru
// #define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

namespace Ast {
    struct Id : std::string {
        using std::string::string;
        using std::string::operator=;
    };
    struct QualId1;
    struct QualId2;

    using IdExpr = boost::variant<              //
        Id,                                     //
        boost::recursive_wrapper<QualId1>, //
        boost::recursive_wrapper<QualId2>>;

    struct QualId1 { IdExpr a, b; };
    struct QualId2 { IdExpr a, b; };
    
    // for demo output
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Id const& id) { return os << "Id(" << quoted(id) << ")"; }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, QualId1 const& id) { return os << "QualId1(" << id.a << "." << id.b << ")"; }
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, QualId2 const& id) { return os << "QualId2(" << id.a << ":" << id.b << ")"; }
} // namespace Ast

using It = std::string_view::const_iterator;

template <typename Attr, typename Skipper>
void run_tests(qi::rule<It, Attr(), Skipper> const& rule_, std::vector<std::string> const& tests) {
    using boost::core::demangle;
    std::cout << "======[ " << demangle(typeid(Attr).name()) << " ]======" << std::endl;
    for (std::string_view test : tests) {
        It f = test.begin(), l = test.end();
        try {
            std::cout << "Parsing: " << quoted(test) << " -> ";
            Attr v;
            bool ok;

            if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Skipper, qi::unused_type>)
                ok = parse(f, l, qi::eps > rule_ > qi::eoi, v);
            else
                ok = phrase_parse(f, l, qi::eps > rule_ > qi::eoi, Skipper{}, v);

            std::cout << (ok ? "OK" : "FAIL") //
                      << " Variant #" << v.which() << "\n -> " << v << "\n";
        } catch (qi::expectation_failure<It> const& ef) {
            auto p = ef.first - test.begin();
            auto bol = test.find_last_of( "\r\n", p ) + 1;
            auto line = std::count( f, f + bol, '\n' ) + 1;
            auto eol = test.find_first_of( "\r\n", p );

            std::cout << "EXPECTED " << ef.what_ << " in line:" << line << " col:" << ( p - bol ) << "\n"
                      << "    " << test.substr( bol, eol - bol ) << "\n"
                      << "    " << std::setw( p - bol ) << "" << "^--- here\n";
        }
    }
}

template <typename Attr> using Rule = qi::rule<It, Attr(), qi::space_type>;

int main() {
    using namespace qi::labels;
    using boost::phoenix::construct;
    qi::rule<It, Ast::Id()> id = qi::char_("a-zA-Z_") >> *qi::char_("a-zA-Z0-9_");
    qi::rule<It, Ast::IdExpr(), qi::space_type> expr;
    expr = id[_val = _1] //
        >> *(('.' >> expr)[_val = construct<Ast::QualId1>(_val, _1)] |
             (':' >> expr)[_val = construct<Ast::QualId2>(_val, _1)]);

    run_tests(expr,
              {
                  "abc",
                  "abc.def",
                  "abc:def",
                  "abc.def.ghi",
                  "abc:def:ghi",
                  "abc:def.ghi:jkl",
                  "abc:def:ghi:jkl",
              });
}

Printing
======[ boost::variant<Ast::Id, boost::recursive_wrapper<Ast::QualId1>, boost::recursive_wrapper<Ast::QualId2> > ]======
Parsing: "abc" -> OK Variant #0
 -> Id("abc")
Parsing: "abc.def" -> OK Variant #1
 -> QualId1(Id("abc").Id("def"))
Parsing: "abc:def" -> OK Variant #2
 -> QualId2(Id("abc"):Id("def"))
Parsing: "abc.def.ghi" -> OK Variant #1
 -> QualId1(Id("abc").QualId1(Id("def").Id("ghi")))
Parsing: "abc:def:ghi" -> OK Variant #2
 -> QualId2(Id("abc"):QualId2(Id("def"):Id("ghi")))
Parsing: "abc:def.ghi:jkl" -> OK Variant #2
 -> QualId2(Id("abc"):QualId1(Id("def").QualId2(Id("ghi"):Id("jkl"))))
Parsing: "abc:def:ghi:jkl" -> OK Variant #2
 -> QualId2(Id("abc"):QualId2(Id("def"):QualId2(Id("ghi"):Id("jkl"))))


Preempting your likely next step on the way, I added a bonus approach assuming a recursive expression AST: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/259dd10e93cef8a2

As usual, excellent, educational, and thorough answer!

great example - fixing my rules accordingly

i thought a while about it - what about a typical C syntax like  int a; func1(); - isnt int and a and func1 here an id-rule that will fail with strict expection points? is it just imposible to have good error reporting with a C like grammar?
